# In Blender, how to detect limb collision of a rigged character

Tags: python, collision-detection, blender, rigid-bodies

I am currently working on blender and rigged a character. 
I random set the pose and sometimes the limb will penetrate to other limbs. Ex. if you rotate the arm inwards too much it will penetrate into the body which is not proper.

Is there a way to detect such collision in blender? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, blender doesn't provide any collision detection when you are animating a character. It is up to the animator to see undesired mesh intersections and pose the character as to avoid them while animating.

There is a [collision system](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/collision.html) available as part of the physics simulation but it is only used by objects that are controlled by the physics simulation.